# PUT method doesn't work on Wordpress REST API

Tags: json, api, postman, wordpress-rest-api

let me explain my problem
In my wordpress site I installed the WP REST API plugin to be able to read some listing fields via API

With postman if I use

```
GET https://mysitecom/wp-json/wp/v2/job-listings/1010
```

I get the following json correctly:

```
{
    "id": 10565,
    ...
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "job_listing",
    "title": "first try",
    ...
    "_company_whatsapp": "",
    "_company_mobile": "3331234567",
    "_company_website": "",
    "_company_use_social_networks": "",
    "_company_facebook": "",
    "_company_instagram": "",
    ...
}
```

If I want to edit 2 fields and use

```
PUT https://mysitecom/wp-json/wp/v2/job-listings/1010
```

with the following json:

```
{
    "title": "edit try",
    "_company_mobile": "3339999999",
}
```

It change the title but not the phone number.
If I try to change only the number with

```
{
    "_company_mobile": "3339999999",
}
```

Postman returns this to me

```
{
    "code": "rest_invalid_json",
    "message": "JSON with invalid body was passed.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "json_error_code": 4,
        "json_error_message": "Syntax error"
    }
}
```

I'm approaching the use of APi for the first time, what am I doing wrong? What is the problem and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This json is invalid:

```
{
    "_company_mobile": "3339999999",
}
```

You should remove the comma:

```
{
    "_company_mobile": "3339999999"
}
```

Normally this is expected behaviour for PUT. You can skip fields only if they are optional. You cant pass only the field you want to update. Think of PUT like overwrite. The api applies the same validation like it will do for create (POST). Some APIs provide partial update with PATCH verb. Then you can provide only the fields you want to update usually as query params. Not sure what is exactly the case with Wordpress api.

Comment: I thank you for the answer. Through a GET I took the entire json returned from an already created and published listing, then I pasted it the same with the PUT, modifying only the _company_mobile value, so as to be sure to insert any mandatory field. I can publish and modify everything, through the fields starting with _company (there are _company_mobile, _company_whatsapp, _company address...) Maybe there are some kind of permissions to be able to use GET, POST and PUT??

Comment: Can you provide reference to the api docs? Normally if you are not allowed to do something you should get 403 as status code.